# Windows 8 Bluescreen when initiating suspend

Tags: windows-8, bsod, suspend

I had the same problem in windows server 2012 but decided to try and rebuild it with a windows 8.

**System info:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zf1je91cn2cbc89/DxDiag.txt

Doesn't happen when using Hybernate.

**Minidumps:** https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1vrwsj56nxesta8/M_d35YgdNx

**Event Viewer:**

System

Provider
[ Name] Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power [ Guid] {331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}

EventID 41

Version 3

Level 1

Task 63

Opcode 0

Keywords 0x8000000000000002

TimeCreated
[ SystemTime] 2013-04-22T18:08:23.729439200Z

EventRecordID 741

Correlation

Execution
[ ProcessID] 4 [ ThreadID] 8

Channel System

Computer Server

Security
[ UserID] S-1-5-18

EventData

BugcheckCode 307 BugcheckParameter1 0x0 BugcheckParameter2 0x281 BugcheckParameter3 0x280 BugcheckParameter4 0x0 SleepInProgress 0 PowerButtonTimestamp 0 BootAppStatus 3221225473

At this point I'm clueless. The whole reason for suspending is thats it's a 'server' configured with lightsout. (Sleeping and waking when another computer in it's list gets online).

If somebody could provide some insight that would be lovely.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Information about the CPU is required to help.

Comment: Well there was a reason for the dxdiag file!
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2300 CPU @ 2.80GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.8GHz

Comment: I don't have access to Dropbox at my current location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RocketRAID 2680 SAS Controller driver (rr2680.sys) seams to cause the crash. Get an updated driver:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, A single DPC or ISR exceeded its time allotment. The offending
    component can usually be identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000281, The DPC time count (in ticks).
Arg3: 0000000000000280, The DPC time allotment (in ticks).
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  SINGLE_DPC_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_c000000f:  FFFFF88000E1BFB0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80184de15df to fffff80184c88040

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`00e1b480  fffff880`00e1b540
fffff880`00e1b488  fffff801`85377eba hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0x86
fffff880`00e1b490  ffffffff`ffd0d9a0
fffff880`00e1b498  fffff801`853a1906 hal!HalpKInterruptHeap+0x906
fffff880`00e1b4b0  fffffa80`077a9da0
fffff880`00e1b4b8  fffff801`84c814ae nt!KiInterruptDispatchLBControl+0x1ce
fffff880`00e1b4c8  00000000`5931b582
fffff880`00e1b4d0  fffff801`853a19a0 hal!HalpKInterruptHeap+0x9a0
fffff880`00e1b4d8  fffff801`84c57aca nt!EtwpReserveTraceBuffer+0xca
fffff880`00e1b4f8  fffffa80`077a9da0
fffff880`00e1b500  fffff880`014f2ea4 SCSIPORT!SpStartIoSynchronized
fffff880`00e1b538  00000000`00000000
fffff880`00e1b540  00000000`00000000
fffff880`00e1b548  fffff880`014b6ab8*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for rr2680.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for rr2680.sys
 rr2680+0x3ab8
fffff880`00e1b550  00000000`00000000
fffff880`00e1b558  00000000`00000000
fffff880`00e1b560  00000000`00000000
1: kd> lmvm rr2680
start             end                 module name
fffff880`014b3000 fffff880`014ed000   rr2680   T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: rr2680.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rr2680.sys
    Image name: rr2680.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Jun 27 03:44:39 2012
```

Comment: Thats kind of the problem... it is the latest driver.

Comment: contact the support of the card manufacture and request new drivers.

Comment: Already did, they are going to try and reproduce it in their labs because I already have the latest drivers..

Comment: that's the only thing you can do. Wait for their reply and hopefully a future driver update fixes it.